# Elastic Search - search token aliasing

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic search is it possible to search aliases of search tokens, for example, if users are searching for ‘USD’ then they should also get results matching ‘dollar’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are referring is the `synonym search` which can be achieved by creating the additional tokens in your index for `USD`, which is `dollar` in your case, Please read more about [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html). This way now as you have both these tokens present in your inverted index, hence searching for any of this would give the search result.